# Send XML via email using Laravel

Tags: php, xml, email, laravel

I want to send an Email that has XML as content.
I've created a **blade view** for this called `xml_email.blade.php` to which I pass the variables that conform the email.

My `xml_email.blade.php` looks like this:

```
{{ '<'.'?'.'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' }}
<customer>
    <contact>
        <name part="full">{{$customer->name}}</name>
        @if($customer->allow_phone == true)
        <phone>{{$customer->phone}}</phone>
        @endif
        <email>{{$customer->email}}</email>
    </contact>
</customer>
```

And I am sending it like this from a controller

```
Mail::send('emails.xml_email', ['customer' => $customer], function($message){
    $message->to("recipient@email.com", '')->subject('New Customer!');
});
```

The email gets sent however is not in XML format and all the tags are missing.

**Is there a way to change the Mime Type of the email to `text/xml` or to keep all the XML tags when sent?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Escape the XML so it's treated as text. For example "<" would be `"&lt;"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the content-type of your email message.

In Laravel, the `$message` is documented to be a subtype of `Swift_Message` ([reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail)), therefore

```
$message->setContentType($contentType);
```

should do it. So setting it to "`text/xml`" might already do it, see [`Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity::setContentType`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/8449b52825f5df828d9e0213f74c47abb376442d/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php#L166), which is the base classe of `Swift_Message` with the method implementation.

Comment: I tried this approach and it crashes Im doing it like this:
Mail::send('emails.xml_email', ['customer' => $customer], function($message){
    $message->setContentType("text/xml")->to("recipient@email.com", '')->subject('New Customer!');
});

Comment: crash is not an error message. [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456) - please enable logging and then a concrete error message should help to say more.